# ¿Cual es la mejor forma de convertir un string en Capitalize?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Tengo un `string` el cual necesito convertir su valor en `capitalize`. Ejemplo:

```
string cadena = "HOLA MUNDO";
```

Necesito devolver el valor así -> Hola Mundo

¿Cual seria la mejor forma de lograr esto?

Comment: Deberías aceptar la respuesta que tiene más votos, no solo porque hace uso del método `ToTitleCase`, sino también porque la respuesta aceptada hace uso de `Regex`, lo cual me parece un "overkill".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes resolverlo con dos expresiones regulares:

```
var cadena = "HOLA MUNDO";
var result = Regex.Replace(cadena.ToLower(), @"\b(\w)", m => m.Value.ToUpper());
result = Regex.Replace(result, @"(\s(of|in|by|and)|\'[st])\b", m => m.Value.ToLower(), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Tomado de este post de Stack Overflow en ingles: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4315592/2373249

Comment: Gracias ! me sirvió =)

Answer (score 7):

También puede hacerlo de esta forma:

`TextInfo.ToTitleCase()` escribe en mayúscula el primer carácter en cada símbolo de una cadena. Si no es necesario mantener `Acronym Uppercasing`, entonces debe incluir `ToLower()`.

```
string cadena = "HOLA MUNDO";
cadena = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(cadena.ToLower());
```

> Resultado:  "Hola Mundo"

Si `CurrentCulture` no está disponible, use:

```
string cadena = "HOLA MUNDO";
cadena = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("es-ES", false).TextInfo.ToTitleCase(cadena.ToLower());
```

> Vea el [enlace de MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase.aspx) para una descripción detallada.

---

**Forma Larga**:

Puede usar una función como esta:

```
public static string PrimeraLetraMayuscula(string cadena)
{
    switch (cadena)
    {
        case null: throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(cadena));
        case "": throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(cadena)} no puede estar vacío", nameof(cadena));
        default: return cadena.First().ToString().ToUpper() + cadena.Substring(1);
    }
}
```

> Esta función la encuentra en esta respuesta SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4405876/8933039

Comment: Genial ! gracias.

Comment: @vcasas Bien :)

Comment: `input` que seria? ya que el parámetro se llama `cadena`

Comment: @vcasas edité la respuesta, es la costumbre de usar Inglés-Spanish.  Es **cadena** no input

Comment: Parecería que la forma larga sólo capitaliza la primera palabra y no las demás como sí hace el otro método.